# MySQL Multiple Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a table like this:

```
id  image_id  style_id  style_value
-----------------------------------
1   45        24        red
1   45        25        big
1   47        26        small
1   45        27        round
1   49        28        rect
```

I want to take image_id column if:

- `style_id = 24` and `style_value = red`
- `style_id = 25` and `style_value = big`
- `style_id = 26` and `style_value = round`

I have make a query like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT image_id FROM list WHERE (style_id = 24 AND style_value = 'red') AND (style_id = 25 AND style_value = 'big') AND (style_id = 27 AND style_value = 'round')
```

But I couldn't get any result. When I make this sample with OR, it works well. But I have to do this with AND. Because I need image id s which are both "red, big and rect".

I have made lots of search with Google but couldn't fine any solution.

Comment: Is there any dependency between style_id and style_value?  That is, does style_id 24 mean "red", while style_id 25 means "big"?

Comment: Yes, i have another table named "styles". And a style has 5-6 different options. For example: style_id 24 has 5 different options (red, green, yellow, ...).

Comment: Could you provide a `SHOW CREATE TABLE list\G` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE styles\G`, and also provide a few sample rows from the table `styles`?

Comment: Table 1: images

id - image_name
1 - abc 
2 - def
3 - ghi
...

Table 2: Styles
id - style_name - style_values
1 - color - (red-green-blue-etc.) 
2 - shape - (round, rect, etc.) 

I am collection style values as a serialized text in one column. Whenever i create an image i am selecting color from a selectbox and i insert this relation to table 3:

Table 3: relations (as i mentioned in my post)
id - image_id - style_id - style_value

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the expected returned data?

Comment: I just only want to take image_id from association table.

For example as i mentioned in my first post:

I want to take "red, big and round" image_id. It means: 45 (according to table)

Comment: So style_id 24 is always color, style_id 25 is always size, and style_id 26 is always shape.  I think I am following.

Comment: So with the above, would the query not return any rows, as style_id 26 does not equal 'rect'?

Comment: Yes friend, you are right. style_id 24 is always color, style 25 is always size.

Comment: @Lock, You are right. I have made a mistake while writing to stackoverflow. Now, i have fixed it. When style_id 27, it must be round.

Answer (score 52):

I think that you are after this:

```
SELECT image_id
FROM list
WHERE (style_id, style_value) IN ((24,'red'),(25,'big'),(27,'round'))
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING count(distinct style_id, style_value)=3
```

You can't use AND, because values can't be `24 red` and `25 big` and `27 round` at the same time in the same row, but you need to check the presence of `style_id, style_value` in multiple rows, under the same `image_id`.

In this query I'm using IN (that, in this particular example, is equivalent to an OR), and I am counting the distinct rows that match. If 3 distinct rows match, it means that all 3 attributes are present for that `image_id`, and my query will return it.

Comment: Never knew you could group where clauses like that. Nifty.

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT a.image_id 
FROM list a
INNER JOIN list b
   ON a.image_id = b.image_id
   AND b.style_id = 25
   AND b.style_value = 'big'
INNER JOIN list c
   ON a.image_id = c.image_id
   AND c.style_id = 27
   AND c.style_value = 'round'
WHERE a.style_id = 24 
   AND a.style_value = 'red'
```

Answer (score 10):

You will never get a result, it's a simple logic error.

You're asking your database to return a row which has `style_id = 24 AND style_id = 25 AND style_id = 26`. Since 24 is niether 25 nor 26, you will get no result.

You have to use `OR`, then it makes some sense.

Comment: But, there're also both,

image_id (45) => style_id (24),
image_id (45) => style_id (25),
image_id (45) => style_id (26)...

It means that table have 3 different rows with same image_id.

Comment: So you should check also for the same image_id. I'm not quite sure what's the purpose of your SQL.

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you are after, although depending on how many style_id's there are, it would be tricky to implement (not sure if those style_id's are static or not). If this is the case, then it is not really possible what you are wanting as the WHERE clause works on a row to row basis.

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT
    image_id,
    max(decode(style_id,24,style_value)) AS style_colour,
    max(decode(style_id,25,style_value)) AS style_size,
    max(decode(style_id,27,style_value)) AS style_shape
  FROM
    list
  GROUP BY
    image_id
)
SELECT
  image_id
FROM
  cte
WHERE
  style_colour = 'red'
  and style_size = 'big'
  and style_shape = 'round'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa5cf/18

Comment: I have tried in sqlfiddle, but these values aren't static. So i have to convert to into a dynamic version. If i cannot find any practical solution, i can try your solution. Thanks Lock.

Answer (score 2):

```
select unique red24.image_id from 
( 
    select image_id from `list` where style_id = 24 and style_value = 'red' 
) red24
inner join 
( 
    select image_id from `list` where style_id = 25 and style_value = 'big' 
) big25
on red24.image_id = big25.image_id
inner join 
( 
    select image_id from `list` where style_id = 27 and style_value = 'round' 
) round27
on red24.image_id = round27.image_id
```

Comment: thanks. Your code works very well. I just only remove "unique" parameter according my need. Everything is okay right now. Thanks again and have a nice work.

Answer (score 2):

May be using this query you don't get any result or empty result. You need to use `OR` instead of `AND` in your query like below.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT image_id FROM list WHERE (style_id = 24 AND style_value = 'red') OR (style_id = 25 AND style_value = 'big') OR (style_id = 27 AND style_value = 'round');
```

Try out this query.