# Is it possible to get Corresponding Values for related Keys

Tags: mysql

I dont think this is possible as far as my knowledge ,but still trying my luck.

I Have got a Table as shown below

```
+---------+------+
| Item_ID | VAT  |
+---------+------+
|       1 | 5.00 |
|       2 | 7.00 |
|       3 | 3.00 |
+---------+------+
```

In case i pass multiple Item_ID (1,2,3) .

Is it possible to get the corresponding VAT values ??

**Output expected is**

```
5.00
7.00
3.00
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Multiple Where Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046637/mysql-multiple-where-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IN clause to specify a comma separated list of Item_ID to filter the records you want to return. For example:

```
SELECT VAT 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 
Item_ID IN (1, 2, 3);
```