# MySQL query for shopping cart filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the below table for shopping cart

```
id  product_id  attribute_id    value
----------------------------------------
1       1           1           A,B,C
2       2           1           B,C
3       3           1           C
4       1           2           200
5       2           2           150
6       3           2           300
7       1           3           RED
8       2           3           BLUE
9       3           3           RED,GREEN
10      1           4           YES
11      2           4           NO
12      3           4           NO
```

I am able to form a search result from this table. There is a provision to filter the search result by attributes.

Attributes can hold the following types of values:

1. Numeric (250)
2. String (YES/NO)
3. String List (A,B,C)

I need a query to get list of product_id for the below conditions

- attribute_id = 1 and value = B or C
- and
- attribute_id = 2 and value = 150
- and
- attribute_id = 4 and value = NO

I referred a stock question ([MySQL Multiple Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046637/mysql-multiple-where-clause)) and tried but not able to get the actual output.

Comment: Show us what you tried, it will help us understand and you may have been closer to a solution than you thought

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` in your `WHERE` clause and also use brackets to split each condition.

```
SELECT id, product_id, attribute_id, value
FROM shoppingcart
WHERE (attribute_id = 1 AND value IN ('B', 'C'))
OR (attribute_id = 2 AND value = 150)
OR (attribute_id = 4 AND value = 'NO')
```

Comment: It works for OR condition, but I need here is AND. So user want to filter the product having "C" AND "RED" AND "NO" so it should output product_id 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT product_id FROM table_name WHERE 

(attribute_id = 1 AND (
            (value LIKE 'B,%' OR value LIKE '%,B' OR value LIKE '%,B,%' OR value LIKE 'B')
            OR
            (value LIKE 'C,%' OR value LIKE '%,C' OR value LIKE '%,C,%' OR value LIKE 'C')
              )
) 

OR

(attribute_id = 2 AND value = '150')
OR

(attribute_id = 3 AND value = 'NO')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works for OR condition. I need AND condition. For example: need product_id whose attributes having values "C" and "RED" and "NO"
So it should output only the product_id 3
Can you help me